# Removing features with 0 importance is changing the predictions

Tags: machine-learning, classification, importance

I am working on a binary classification model using LightGBM.

After fitting the model, I decided to analyse feature importances. I have found out that values of some of the feature importances are equal to 0. `feature_importances_` is taken as default, so the method is `split`.

I decided to make a test and remove a few of those variables, expecting the results to be the same as before. The model results (predictions for some of the records and hence ROC-AUC scores etc.) are changing. When changing `importance_type` to `gain`, those variables still give value of 0 and removing them still make the same difference in predictions, obviously.

My question is: how come, if those variables have never been used to make even 1 split?

Comment: Their presence influences how the splits occur, even if they are not involved in any splits.

Comment: @Dave, is that something that I can find in LightGBM documentation, or would that be accurate for any kind of ensemble/boosted trees? Thanks for the answer